# Generate a matrix of booleans from another one

Tags: c#

Let's say that I have a `bool[,]` with random values

```
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFTTT
TTTTTTTT
FFFFFFFF
```

What would be the smartest way to create a new `bool[,]` that build on top of the previous one. That means, that it can have random values where the previous one was `true`, but that it preserves the `false`s from the original?

So this could be a possible result

```
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFTFT
TTFFFTTT
FFFFFFFF
```

But this not...

```
TTTTTFFF
TTTTTFFF
TTTTTTTT
FFFFFFFF
```

So far I have come with the classical solution. First create a matrix of random values, and the overwrite them.

```
for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        if (matrix1[x, y] == false)
            matrix2[x, y] = false;
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: So this is about copying `false` values from one matrix to the other?

Comment: Well, that is the way that I did it. But I was wondering if there was a more ellegant way to generate the second matrix from the first one. I want to do sort of "Boolean Pyramids" if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can make this function more generic so that you can use reuse it where necessary and with any type. Currently your code is doing three things:

- Loop over the matrix.
- Checking a condition.
- Modifying the elements.

This can be separated and encapsulated. You first create a general-purpose extension that just loops over any matrix, checks the passed predicate and calls the action:

```
public static T[,] ForEach<T>(
    this T[,] m, 
    Func<T, bool> predicate, 
    Action<T, int, int> action
)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < m.GetLength(0); x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < m.GetLength(1); y++)
            if (predicate(m[x, y])) action(m[x, y], x, y);

    return m;
}
```

---

Example:

Assuming you have these two matrices

```
var m1 = new[,]
{
    { false, false, false, false },
    { false, true, false, true },
    { true, true, false, false },
    { false, false, true, true }
};

var m2 = new[,]
{
    { false, true, true, false },
    { false, true, false, true },
    { true, true, false, false },
    { false, false, false, false }
};
```

you call the new `ForEach` extension like this where you first filter the items with `!m` so that you get only those where `m = false`, then you update the second matrix at the coordinates `[x, y]` with the value `m` of the first matrix.

```
m1.ForEach(m => !m, (m, x, y) => m2[x, y] = m);
```